# Java: error: ")" expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm new to Java so I apologize if this is a silly question.

```
  public static double FibonacciFinder(double number) {
     double fibonacciNumber = ((1/sqrt(5))(Math.pow(((1+sqrt(5))/2),number)-(Math.pow(((1-sqrt(5))/2),number))));
     return fibonacciNumber;    
}
```

and I get the following back

```
Fibonacci.java:29: error: ')' expected
  double fibonacciNumber = ((1/sqrt(5))(Math.pow(((1+sqrt(5))/2),number)-(Math.pow(((1-sqrt(5))/2),number))));
                                       ^

Fibonacci.java:29: error: not a statement
  double fibonacciNumber = ((1/sqrt(5))(Math.pow(((1+sqrt(5))/2),number)-(Math.pow(((1-sqrt(5))/2),number))));
                                                                        ^

Fibonacci.java:29: error: ';' expected
  double fibonacciNumber = ((1/sqrt(5))(Math.pow(((1+sqrt(5))/2),number)-(Math.pow(((1-sqrt(5))/2),number))));
                                                                                                           ^
```

I know this is not the prettiest way to computer the equation, but what exactly is BREAKING what I am doing? There are the correct amounts of parenthesis and everything so I thought it would at least work.

Comment: Count the opening and closing brackets and see if you can see the error. The compiler tells you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing one `*`:

```
double fibonacciNumber = ((1/sqrt(5))*(Math.pow(((1+sqrt(5))/2),number)-(Math.pow(((1-sqrt(5))/2),number))));
```

Comment: Ohhhhh! I was thinking that two parenthesis side by side would automatically multiply. Thank you